# float argument must be a string or a number

Tags: python, list

I have data like this

```
xmax [[111.34999999999999], [111.3], [111.2], [111.09999999999999], [111.05], [111.05]]
```

I want xmax[0]

if i write

```
print xmax[0]
```

I have [111.34999999999999]

I would like to have 111.34999999999999

Comment: And where does the exception message (from the title) come from?

Comment: This is not a sample list, it is a nested list, then you need to loop a nested `list xmax[0][0]`

Comment: The title has no relation with your problem

Comment: & I think you have no idea, about list and nested list, google it before you ask such a question

Comment: Why is your data in a list of 1 item lists, that's not very RAM-efficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to index the nested list:

```
print xmax[0][0]
>>> 111.34999999999999
```

Answer (score 2):

You have a *list of list* so in order to get just the first value you have to:

```
print xmax[0][0]
```

Answer (score 1):

Few ideas.

**Option 0**
This is agnostic of the depth of the nesting.

```
def first(x):
    try:
        return first(x[0])
    except:
        return x

first(xmax)

111.35
```

---

**Option 1**
This assumes one layer of nesting and flattens it.  It's not efficient as it gets an entire flattened list just to return the first element.

```
[x for y in xmax for x in y][0]

111.35
```

---

**Option 2**
This also assumes one layer of nesting but is efficient in getting the first element.

```
from cytoolz import concat

next(concat(xmax))

111.35
```